# Hibernate "Column --- cannot be null

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, jersey-2.0

I'm using Hibernate in combination with phpmyadmin (MySQL).
Recently I found a really weird error.
Whenever I try to insert a new row (.persist) I get the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'user_id' cannot be null
```

The error is really obvious.
But the weird part is, this error came out of nowhere.
I'm ENTIRELY sure the property userId (mapped to 'user_id') isn't null. I tested several times.
This is the mapping part:
(On the @manytoone part).

```
  <property name="userId" update="false" insert="false" column="user_id" type="java.lang.Long" />
```

The OneToMany part isn't the problem I guess.

So the problem here is, i'm 100% sure the value isn't null, still Hibernate passes it as null to the MySQL. (Getter does work).

**UPDATE**

@ManyToOne side, which causes the error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="xx.xx.xx.AlarmEntity" table="alarms">
        <meta attribute="class-description">
            Hierin staan de object properties van de alarm entiteit.
        </meta>
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" column="id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="keepsRunning"  type="java.lang.Boolean">
            <column name="keeps_running" sql-type="int"></column>
        </property>
        <property name="userId" update="false" insert="false" column="user_id" type="java.lang.Long" />
        <many-to-one name="userAlarm" cascade="save-update" fetch="select" column="user_id" class="xx.xx.xx.UserEntity" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: `<property name="userId" update="false" insert="true" column="user_id" type="java.lang.Long" />`  
Check this

Comment: What is the problem there? my column is called "user_id" and the property which does the @ManyToOne (the id linked) is called userId.  **Update, the insert true part , i try that ;)

Comment: Did you try that..Still not working..?

Comment: The error states tht userId valu is null. You have to set it before saving or give some Strategy to generate it

Comment: @Hema `org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: ipass.server.domain.AlarmEntity column: user_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false"` get this error. And I'm 100% certain the value isn't null... I check several times, when receiving and before inserting. It also did happen out of nowhere without changing the code.

Comment: @Hema, when i set `insert=true` I get the exception I explained above (Repeated column in mapping for entity, MappingException).

Comment: So you will be having two columns mapped with same name. Can you post your entire mapping code

Comment: @Hema, i updated my original answer with the mapping code which causes the issue.

Comment: `<property name="userId" update="false" insert="false" column="user_id" type="java.lang.Long" />
        <many-to-one name="userAlarm" cascade="save-update" fetch="select" column="user_id" class="xx.xx.xx.UserEntity" />` see u have used user_id two times and hence you are getting that error

Comment: @Hema, but one is the property id, to insert. The other is the mapped object to get in my json response. I need both, so how can I solve it?

Comment: Yeah. will solve it

Comment: @Hema, thank you for looking into it :)

Answer (score 2):

Please check the mapping

**UserEntity**

```
private int user_id;
private Set<AlarmEntity> alarm;
```

**AlarmEntity**

```
private int alarm_id;
private String keepsRunning;
```

As per your requirement , I have provided mapping with annotation please check

**User**

```
@Id
@Column(name = "userId")
private Long userId;

// parent to Alarm
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "userId")
@JsonIgnore 
private List<Alarm> alarmList ;
```

**Alarm**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "alarmId")
private Long alarmId;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "userId", insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable = true)
private User user;

@Column(name="keepsRunning")
private String keepsRunning;
```

Comment: But one use has multiple Alarms, I don't understand why you defined @many-to-one in the UserEntity. The code is just the same code i provided, but with mistakes. Maybe I just remove the user_id and alarm_id and see if it works..

Comment: I have provided mapping as an example to your code. Its not exact to your requirement. U dint tell me your exact mappings. So take it as a reference if helps or else let me kw any changes u need

Comment: Yes thank you, I now temporarly removed the "double" mapping, so the @manytoone, as it works with only the "userid" field. It breaks becouse of the double mapping. But I also need to keep the userid field, becouse I need to insert this.

Comment: So now what is the issue..?

Comment: That I can't get the userEntity linked to the AlarmEntity :) when I request the AlarmEntity in my JSON response , I need the UserEntity (owner of the AlarmEntity) aswell returned in the same response. So I need the @manytoone property. But Hibernate doesn't let me combine that with the userId, as both use the "user_id" column, so you get double mapping. But when I remove the userId property completely I can't insert it anymore when I create a new AlarmEntity. So I need a way to use the userId property with the userAlarm property and still insert it as user_id (so Long and not UserEntity).

Comment: please tell your mapping correctly..? You will have like`for one user many alarms` am i right. If this is the case u need `oneToMany` mapping not `manyToOne`                                                                                                        Are you supposed to do this using `annotations`.?

Comment: I have provided mapping as per requirement with annotations.Please check it.Its working code I have verified and added here

Answer (score 0):

Providing Annotation Approach one to Many Example which worked for me

In below example Factory can have multiple product ,that means there is one to many mapping between Factory and Product where Product is owning side of this relationship which means Product will maintain foreign key constraint for holding factory id.

**Table structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE `factory` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `factory_name` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `factory_id` bigint NOT NULL ,
  `product_name` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

ALTER TABLE product
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_product_factory
FOREIGN KEY (factory_id) REFERENCES factory (id);
```

**Entity Structure:**

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = “factory”)
public class Factory {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name=“id”)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "factory_name")
    private String factoryName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = “factory”,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
}
@Entity
@Table(name = “product”)
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = “product_name")
    private String productName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name=“factory_id")
    private Factory factory;
}
```

**Service Structure:**

```
    @Service 
    public class ProductService {
    
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private FactoryRepository factoryRepository;
    
    public void saveFactoryAndProduct(){
       
        Factory factory = new Factory();
        factory.setFactoryName("F1");
        Product product1 = new Product();
        product1.setProductName("P1");
        factory.getProducts.add(product1);
        product.setFactory(factory);
    
        Product product2 = new Product();
         product2.setProductName("P2");
        factory.getProducts.add(product2);
        product1.setFactory(factory);
    
        //Saving factory will also saved linked product1 and product2 data having factory_id as a foreign key from Factory table
        factoryRepository.save(factory);
    }
    }
```

**Note:**
Saving Products with Mapped Factory.Here we don't need to save product specifically since Factory is maintaining cascade so when we save factory related products will also save but we just need to setFatory for every product object inorder to maintain foreign key in product.